# JQM .bind function call hangs on a method, but script still completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm just getting started with Javascript, jQuery, and jQuery Mobile. I'm trying to go through a tutorial online, but I'm getting caught up on the mobileinit event handler.  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        Notes.testHelper.createDumyNotes();
        Notes.controller.init();
    });
</script>
```

If I put an alert before and right after Notes.testHelper.createDummyNotes(); the alert is called. However, if I put the alert right after Notes.controller.init(), the alert isn't called. I imagine this means the code stopped in that function.  However, if I put an alert right before the closing script tag outside of the function, that alert is called--This is what confuses me. How can a method hang and not allow the rest of a function to complete but still let the script complete?

As an interesting aside, I forgot to put the script tags around this .bind function at first, and the html was styled correctly.  However, once I put the tags around this function, the html appeared but wasn't styled.

Any suggestions? As I said, I'm new to javascript, so this could be a fundamental misunderstanding of the way the language executes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { ... }` will be called when the `mobileinit` event is triggered, which will be AFTER the code between the `script` tags are read. This is why the `alert` you placed just before the closing `script` tag is executed.

If you put `alert(1);` before the closing tag, and `alert(2);` after the `function() {` and `alert(3)` after the `createDumyNotes()`, you will probably get `1` and `2` but not `3`.

I think you're on the right path in that the error is occurring in the `createDumyNotes()` function. I suggest you get into that function with some `try { ... } catch(e) { ... }` and pinpoint where the error is occurring (assuming `Notes` and `Notes.testHelper` are valid objects, and `Notes.testHelper.createDumyNotes()` is an existing function.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that your function is `createDumyNotes()` instead of `createDummyNotes()`. Is this nothing more than a misspelling?

Comment: It was a misspelling. I corrected it but still nothing.  I think the .createDummyNotes() function is working, as the alert executes after that method call, but not after the .controller.init() method.

Comment: What you said is correct.  I see the alerts in that order except the function fails in .controller.init(), though.  When I place an alert at the beginning of the Controller file AND at the beginning of .init(), neither are reached.

Comment: Another update: I replaced my entire Controller file with the source code the developer provided (which I assume is correct), and it still won't work, which leads me to believe it's a software issue.  The only thing is is that I have about 4 other script files and they all run as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok. Without any other information on the code or where this notes code is from, I can't provide much more of an answer. But make sure that you are actually importing the script file into your document a la `<script type="text/javascript" src="correct-path-here.js"></script>` and test that `Notes` is actually an object.